# Wcf REST Service and Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

Hello I was searching for long time, but every answers didn`t resolved my problem. I have REST Service

```
namespace WcfService1
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "images")]
    List<MyImage> getImages();        
}
[DataContract]
public class MyImage
{
    public MyImage(string name, Image img)
    {
        Name = name;
        Img = img;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Image Img
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Here is implementation:

```
namespace WcfService1
{

public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public List<MyImage> getImages()
    {
        List<MyImage> images = new List<MyImage>();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.jpg");

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Image im = Image.FromFile(file);
            images.Add(new MyImage(file, im));
        }
        return images;
    }
}
}
```

Web.Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <configuration>
      <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
         <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">        
         </endpoint>
        </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
         </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
         <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Next I created Client App and added Service Reference and choose reference from localhost declared upper

There is code of client

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServiceReference1.RestServiceImplClient service = new ServiceReference1.RestServiceImplClient();

        ServiceReference1.MyImage[] images = service.getImages();
        service.Close();
        List<ServiceReference1.MyImage> files = images.Select(im => new ServiceReference1.MyImage() { Img = im.Img, Name = im.Name }).ToList();

        listViewImages.ItemsSource = files;

    }
}
```

On this line:

```
ServiceReference1.MyImage[] images = service.getImages();
```

I have exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:55008/RestServiceImpl.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

When I looked into InnerException I have:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Here is my app.config file for Client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:55008/RestServiceImpl.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IRestServiceImpl">
   </endpoint>
  </client>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I know that the topic is very popular, but all the answers couldn`t help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you have posted, the service web.config does not have an endpoint with BasicHttpBinding. To consume the service through a proxy, I believe you need to add an endpoint with BasicHttpBinding as the per the client web.config in your question. It does expose a REST endpoint. To invoke the REST service, you can invoke using the url like below.

```
http://localhost:55008/RestServiceImpl.svc/images
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Web Reference of REST Service instead of Service Reference in your client code.